# Topology of abstract varieties over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

What are the known restrictions on the topology of complex manifolds corresponding to analytifications of smooth proper algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$? I think 
they have to have non-zero $b_2$ but other than that?

I am asking because there lots of results on topology of Kaehler manifolds and smooth complex projective varieties. However, an abstract variety admits a Kaehler metric iff it is projective so most of those results do not direct apply to abstract non-projective varieties. I wonder which theorems survive and which don't.

Comment: A smooth compact complex algebraic variety satisfies the same Hodge symmetry properties as a projective one (in particular, $b_p$ is even for $p$ odd). This is a nontrivial fact, proved by Deligne in *Théorème de Lefschetz et critères de dégénérescence de suites spectrales*, Pub. math. I.H.É.S. 35 (1968), Proposition 5.3.

Comment: Also, note that any smooth proper variety is birational to a smooth projective variety and the fundamental group is a birational invariant.